# Bot emulator calling/accessing the wrong Message Controller

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, botframework

In my VS solution, there are 3 projects as below:

1) Bot2015
2) Bot2015_2 (**Startup Project**)
3) DB

[image: solution]

Bot2015_2 is my Startup Project but whenever I try to test the Bot2015_2 bot application via emulator, it calls the Message Controller of the first project i.e. Bot2015 (that is the issue here). It should access the Message Controller of the start up project i.e. Bot2015_2. Even if I unload the Bot2015 and test the application, same thing is happening, it never calls the correct Message Controller i.e. of Bot2015_2.

Please help me on this!

Thank You.

Comment: Is the port number in Bot2015_2 is the same on what you type on your emulator? Different projects should have different port numbers.

Comment: It is the default port number 3979 in both projects. How to change the port number if this is the issue because it was working fine earlier?

Comment: Nope, different projects uses different port numbers since this is somehow a web app but applied on bot framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check what port are you using to communicate with your emulator. This is what the emulator use to communicate with your controllers.

> To specify a port for a Web application project that uses IIS Express
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the application and then select Properties.
>      Click the Web tab.
> 2. In the Servers section, under Use Local IIS Web server, in the Project URL box change the port number.
> 3. To the right of the Project URL box, click Create Virtual Directory, and then click OK.
> 4. In the File menu, click Save Selected Items.
> 5. To verify the change, press CTRL+F5 to run the project.
>      The new port number appears in the address bar of the browser.

You can check more info here: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.ASPX)

Comment: Yes, it was indeed related to same port numbers in both the projects. Followed the above steps, now its working fine. Thanks Willy David Jr.